# What topic is this? Any advice on where to go to understand these types of questions?

Tags: real-analysis

Sorry if this is not how I'm supposed to use this site but it's my only sense of direction.

I want to know what topics these are and if there are any videos or articles that would help understand how to solve them. My lecture note's aren't great?

Cheers.

[image]

Comment: Hint: If $b=10$ then each term of the series is a decimal term in the expansion of $x$.

Comment: What exactly is the "this" in your "What topic is this?"? Do you just mean the general lore of summations? Or is there something about these *specific* summations that piques your interest?

Comment: @Blue "this" as in "sequences,recursion" what topic isit when series converge with a sum in a certain range?